# number of solutions to $x+y+z=n$ where $x,y,z$ are positive integers OR $0$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Using a stars and bars argument, I can solve this question when $x,y,z$ are required to be positive integers. In stars and bars language, we will have $n$ bars, and since each variable must be positive, we have $n-1$ choices of where to put each bar. Choosing 2 bars partitions our stars into 3 sets, the cardinality of each set represents a possible value of the respective variable.

Thus when $x,y,z$ are required to be positive integers, the answer is ${n-1}\choose{2}$

How do I adjust this arguement when the variables can be zero? Thanks, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: The number of positive integer solutions to $x+y+z=n$ is the same as the number of positive integer solutions to $(x-1)+(y-1)+(z-1)=(n-3)$.  Now, note that $x$ positive integer makes $(x-1)$ non-negative integer.  Equivalently, the number of non-negative integer solutions to $x+y+z=n$ is equal to the number of non-negative integer solutions to $(x+1)+(y+1)+(z+1)=(n+3)$

Comment: Sorry.. edited title again!! ugh

Comment: Alternatively phrased, rather than in stars and bars choosing distinct positions *between* stars to place the bars... just arrange the stars and bars together freely where we don't require bars be placed in different spaces between.  There are $n$ stars and $2$ bars here for a total of $n+2$ objects to arrange, $n$ of which being stars.

Comment: @JMoravitz Say $n=4$. Then we have 2 bars to place and a total of 6 objects to arrange. However, the answer will not be $6!$ because the stars are indistinguishable from eachother. Can you expand on your idea for me? I'm sure it's perfectly clear, I'm just not so great at this stuff!

Comment: The number of positive integer solutions to $\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+\dots+x_k = n\\x_i>0\end{cases}$ will be $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.  The number of non-negative integer solutions to $\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+\dots+x_k = n\\x_i\geq 0\end{cases}$ will be $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$.  In your example, the $6$ objects to arrange, four of them are identical stars and two are identical bars... choose which two positions are for the bars to give $\binom{6}{2}$ ways of arranging, not $6!$.  See more at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: Thank you for your patience!!

Comment: You can expand on my first comment and use the technique of "change of variables" to further adjust the problem to solve things like finding the number of integer solutions to $\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+x_3=n\\x_1\geq 1\\x_2\geq 5\\ x_3\geq -2\end{cases}$, here setting $y_1=x_1-1, y_2=x_2-5, y_3=x_3+2$ we see that $y_1+y_2+y_3=n-4$ and each $y_i$ are any non-negative integers giving $\binom{(n-4)+3-1}{3-1}$ solutions, transforming an unknown problem into a known problem, into whichever format you are most comfortable.  I personally prefer the non-negative integer form the most.

Comment: Wow! So simple. Thank you so much!!!